# SQL - exclude all items containing 'foo' except those with 'foo bar'

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run a query in mysql that will exclude all items containing the wording 'foo xxx' or just 'foo', but including the specific entry 'foo bar'.

How to do this?

Comment: I think this covers it: `WHERE (column NOT LIKE 'foo ___' AND column <> 'foo') or column = 'foo bar'` (assuming `xxx` meant any three characters and not literal `xxx`).

Comment: "or just 'foo'" meaning the value is foo or the value contains foo?  add a lot of examples and show what you have tried; that will help enormously

Comment: Or answering the different question in your title `WHERE column NOT LIKE '%foo%' OR column = 'foo bar'`

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way:

```
SELECT  *
FROM test
WHERE col1 regexp  '(^|[[:space:]])foo([[:space:]]|$)'
AND  col1 regexp  '(^|[[:space:]])bar([[:space:]]|$)';
```

Above query will return only the rows in which both foo and bar are present and separate it doesn't matter the order

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0555bcc45ba479489b0367a0b08ae858

A good article on REGEXP:https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mysql-cookbook/0596001452/ch04s08.html

Have a look on [MySQL Full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html)